# How to use GTMAppAuth in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-directory-api

I do not know how to code in Objective-C and have to get an app working with the G Suite SDK so that I can get information about members of the groups. The problem is that [in September Google changed](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) how auth requests work, [so this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) no longer works. I know I need to switch over to using [GTMAppAuth](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth), but it's all Objective-C.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Have you tried reading the documentation and implementing the authentication? If you need the to swift, you can simply use a bridging header. Are you looking for an example?

Comment: Using a bridging header didn't let me use the code from the example. For example, Objective-C has `OIDServiceConfiguration` but that was unrecognized in Swift. An example in how to do this in Swift would be excellent.

Comment: Any updates? I am stuck at this as well.

Comment: @UmarFarooque It's something that, at this moment, we have abandoned to make progress elsewhere, but I was about to get a little bit of progress. I don't know Objective-C well, but was able to convert the code on this page https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth and get some stuff. I still couldn't get information on what users are part of what groups or anything else, but hopefully this can help you. If you get that user info, let me know, I'd love to get mine working.

Comment: Ok.. I am working on it.

Comment: @CodyHarness
I have integerated the methods for use with Drive api and contacts api. Tell me where exactly you are stuck ? I'll try to post the swift version of the answer.

Comment: Any update to this? Would be super helpful..

Comment: @markocalvocruz Unfortunately, we scraped the idea of using anything with Google or G Suite, and all of the code was removed. If I recall correctly, I had to just use work from method names used in the example and convert it to Swift that way, but I really don't have anything to go back to and check out. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on YouTube Data API and trying to implement functions in Swift. The following is what I did:

1. Install GTMAppAuth using Cocoapods.
2. Add bridging header and import necessary headers.
3. The above 2 steps didn't result in a successful compilation, since xcode can't find the headers. I manually add header search path in build settings.

After doing these steps, I can access those Objective-C class & methods from Swift classes.

For the "how to use GTMAppAuth" part, I found an example here (though I haven't test it)
https://github.com/Alder85/AppAuthSwift

Maybe you can also find some hints here.

(Sorry for that this is just my experience and may not be a complete answer. I am new here in the stackoverflow and have too little reputations to post a comment.)

Comment: I've integrated GTMAppAuth with my Swift app by following the steps in my answer. I can successfully request user's youtube permissions via OIDAuthState class as stated in [GTMAppAuth Github](https://github.com/google/GTMAppAuth) (the configuration & authorizing sections). Code for authorization is the same as the Github one, I just rewrote it in Swift.

Comment: So i have been plagued by this similar problem for the Gmail API's on iOS. I eventually found a super cool and super simple library that wraps all the Obj C inconsistency and exposes a simple interface. Thank and Bless the Author : Jonas-Taha El Sesiy . GitHub:   https://github.com/elsesiy/GAppAuth